# Google Map : Get center point of map in respect of map div in html

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Please help me, i have some queries regarding google map API

Please concern 3rd point first

1. Is it possible to get the center point of map regarding map div in HTML (like my map div is 100px height and 100px width, then i get the center point lat long for 50,50px), i use the map.getCenter(); but it give the map center point
2. Is it possible on zoom_changed event my marker not sift on the browser screen it change the position with respect of zoom_changed event and stay same on browser screen ?

For example for point 2nd

Initially i have the map with marker set on London
[image]

But when i zoom in then the 
[image]

3. Can i get the coordinates(lat long) with respect of net image place on map 
   [image]

If have any suggestion and solution please reply

Comment: I don't understand the requirements for point `2`. Point `1` don't make any sense either, your `div` is essentially just a container for the map. So when you are looking for the centre view of your container... I don't know what you mean. To me, it would make more sense if you are looking for the center point of a set of markers or something along that.

Comment: @Samuel Toh please see the updated post

Comment: If you are looking at shifting the marker's position you would have to update it's LatLng coordinates accordingly on occurance of a zoom event. As for how much? You defined the amount. Care to share why you are looking at shifting the markers on zoom? Asking because you are implementing a very unusual behaviour.

Comment: can i get the new lat long according to zoom event to show the marker on same position

Comment: Sorry I'm a little bit confused here. Getting the latLng according to the zoom event? do you mean getting the existing view's latLng?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120071/discussion-between-tarzan-and-samuel-toh).

Answer (score 0):

1) The center point of the html div and that of the map will be the same. Using the same example that you have put if the map div is 100px height and 100px width, then center lat long should be 50,50px which is exactly what map.getCenter() will return.

2) Yes you can use the zoom changed event to move the marker to the center of the map. You will need to call the initZoomChanged method as given below. You can replace "centerMarker" with the name of your marker

3) Haven't really understood what you are trying to do here. Could you provide some more clarification?

The code for creating a marker at the map center and then keeping it in the center of the map after zoom in or zoom out is given below :

```
var centerMarker;

 function createMarker()
 {
     var myLatLng =  {lat: 51.5074, lng: 0.1278}
     centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatLng,
         map: map,
         title: 'Map Center'
       });
 }

 function initZoomChanged()
 {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        centerMarker.setPosition(center);
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, In 3rd point net image is placed on map and i want the coordinates of covered map area by net image

Comment: Is the net image added as an overlay?

Comment: i made a div conataing net image and i put this image on map via css